# Android 5+ screen locks can't add view with WindowManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-windowmanager, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I've got an Identified call app which worked very good till android 5+.

Basically I've got a BroadcastReceiver which "do his thing" when phone rings after identifying the call I add a small view.

on a new galaxy edge s6 it doesn't work when the phone is locked.

here is my related code

```
wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, // TYPE_PHONE
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            wm.addView(app.PhoneLayout, params);
```

app.PhoneLayout contains the layout after inflating etc..

Does anyone have any idea why such thing happen? and how am I able to fix that so that my view will be shown even when the phone is locked?

It's working fine on older devices.

Hope someone can share his thoughts on this

Comment: don't use WindowManager if you can, it is a never ending source of problems, since android devs are trying cheat google devs and vice versa

Comment: whats the alternative?

Comment: changed TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY solved the problem
but now my view is not responding to any action :(

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks